# How to define xpath for link element under tag <a>

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to find xpath  for my robotframework script using below code.

Log To Console    Click Port-Forward tab in Firewall UI page
     Click Button  `xpath=//span[contains(@class, 'tabmenu-item-forwards active' and text()='Port Forwards']`
     Sleep  45s

## Below is html/xml code from my inspect window:

```
<li class="tabmenu-item-zones ">
<li class="tabmenu-item-forwards active">
<a href="/cgi-bin/luci/admin/network/firewall/forwards">Port Forwards</a>
</li>
<li class="tabmenu-item-rules ">
<li class="tabmenu-item-custom ">
</ul>
```

I wanted to click on this Inner text Port Forwards.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//a[.='Port Forwards']
```

This also could be helpful for you -> http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use below Xpath:

```
//li[@class='tabmenu-item-forwards active']/a[contains(.,'Port Forwards')]
```

Comment: what would be the benefit in this particular case to use selector for containing text (your recommendation //li[@class='tabmenu-item-forwards active']/a[contains(.,'Port Forwards')]) instead of the one for containing text 'Port Forwards' exactly? (//a[.='Port Forwards']) ? If there is another element containing this text (ex: Port Forwards 2) then the selector could match the wrong element..

Comment: I believe my xpath will select preciously one element if no more same class name is present while if your xpath can return mutiple if Port Forwards text present in any a tag